# Editing GeoJSON parsing code to parse JSON code instead in SQL

Tags: postgresql, json

Apologies if this is an easy question to some, I have spent hours trying to figure this out and it has me stumped.

So, I know GeoJSON takes the following format:

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -85.6442940021,37.6116333423 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "National Park":"Abraham Lincoln Birthplace NHS",
    "$ Obligated":"$34,584",
    "State":"KY"
    }
  },
```

For this, I have a code in SQL as follows which will parse the GeoJSON which is contained in 1 row of a table out into the appropriate columns in which I need:

```
CREATE TABLE new AS SELECT type, TEXT((prop->>'National Park')::TEXT)National_Park, 
TEXT((prop->>'Obligated')::TEXT)Obligated, 
TEXT((prop->>'State')::TEXT)State, 
geom FROM (SELECT elem->'type' AS type, elem->'properties' 
AS prop, elem->'geometry' AS geom 
FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(data) 
elem FROM table)
f1)f2);
```

My result is then

```
| type | National Park | Obligated | State | geom |
| -------- | -------------- | ------| ------| ------
| FeatureCollection   | Abraham Lincoln Birthplace NHS | $34,584 | KY | "Point", "coordinates":  [ -85.6442940021,37.6116333423 ] |
```

So my struggle is, I now have JSON files which are in the structure:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Johnson, Smith, and Jones Co.",
    "amount":345.33,
    "Remark":"Pays on time"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Sam \"Mad Dog\" Smith",
    "amount":993.44,
    "Remark":""
  },
```

I'd like to edit the same code above to parse out the JSON in the same way as the GeoJSON, except I'm not sure how to as a JSON isn't broken up into named arrays such as properties, etc which I use in my original code

Comment: Unrelated but: `TEXT((prop->>'Obligated')::TEXT)` can be simplified to `prop->>'Obligated'`